# How to set a seed for random number generation

Tags: random, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, random-seed

From what I understand, there is no built-in function in Google Sheets that allows you to set a seed for RAND() or RANDBETWEEN().

My goal is to create a list of psuedo-random integers, within a range, using a function that will produce different (though, not necessarily unique) values based on:

- Which cell is running the function
- And the value in a second cell that contains a seed of my choosing

I need it to produce the same value every time the function is run in a particular cell, with a particular seed.

What is the simplest way to achieve this, so that someone who isn't me and has no programming knowledge can easily use the formula in other cells, as they need to?

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. You should include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read How to Ask.

Comment: Hi Anantha, thank you for responding. I am not able to provide code that I have tried because I have been unable to find any means that will work, and have, therefore, had nothing to try. My searching has come up empty, which is why I came here. I have read How to Ask, and I did my best to fit as many of the criteria as possible. I feel my question is very clear, if there is something that confuses you about it, please let me know, and I will edit the question as necessary to help out.

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

Use VLOOKUP and ADDRESS

## Explation

Create a simple table with two columns, one for a compound key made from the cell address and the "seed" the other for the "seudo-random integers" (SRI)

### Simple table

Sheet name: Table

Sheet content (for illustrative purposes):

```
 |  A   |  B   | 
1|key   |  SRI |
2|A1-1  |    1 |
3|A1-2  |   77 |
```

### Formula

```
=VLOOKUP(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4,FALSE)&"-1",Table!A2:B,2,0)
```